# How to choose the closest object considering size

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on an agent based simulation. I want each agent to choose which other agent to focus on. There are a lot of different inputs, but here I'm asking about the vision one. So the agent has to see which other agent is closest also considering size. They should care about bigger things more than smaller things, a tiny agent very close is not as big of an issue as a huge agent a tiny bit away. It seems fine so far except that considering who is closest and big also considers others that are out of the visual range.

I have this so far:

```
# both seen and viewer are two different groups
def sight(seen, viewer)
    for entity in viewer:
# This is needed later to decide which way to go, not used here
        currentDir = entity.Direction
# Figure out where the viewer is
        pos = pygame.math.Vector2(entity.rect.centerx, entity.rect.centery)
# Find out who is closest. 
# Uses viewer location and location of each agent in the other group to see who is closest. 
# At the end, divided by size*size of the agent in the other group (for height / width).
# Otherwise they'd pay attention to a tiny agent that's close by 
# instead of a huge agent that's just a bit further away.
        closeby = min([e for e in seen.sprites()], key=lambda e: (pos.distance_to(pygame.math.Vector2(e.rect.centerx, e.rect.centery)) / (e.size * e.size)))
        vector = pygame.math.Vector2((entity.rect.centerx - closeby.rect.centerx), (entity.rect.centery - closeby.rect.centery))
# Get the distance to that other agent
        distance = math.hypot(entity.rect.centerx - closeby.rect.centerx, entity.rect.centery - closeby.rect.centery)
# They can't see forever, so they have a sight limit
            if distance < entity.sight:
                Blah blah, rest of the code here
```

Here's the problem: The "if distance < entity.sight" coming AFTER they choose "closeby" means that they might "choose" a big agent as the closeby who is then eliminated because they're too far away.

Imagine this: I'm agent X. There's someone small I should worry about (agent Y) who is within my visual range. However, there's someone (agent Z) who is really big that is outside of my visual range. Agent Z is so big I choose him as the "closeby". Then he's outside of the visual range so no one gets selected by the "if distance < entity.sight". Now no one is selected even though agent Y is close enough he should have been selected.

I feel like either the search

```
closeby = min([e for e in etc etc etc
```

should be limited to who is within the visual range (but I don't know how to do that), or that if the agent chosen as "closeby" is outside of the visual range, the SECOND closest should be chosen. If they're again out of the visual range, the THIRD closest should be chosen, etc, until it gets someone in the visual range. But I'm not sure how to do that either.

Any help anyone can offer in restricting "min([e for e in blah blah" or for choosing the next min in that group if the first doesn't mean "entity.sight" criteria would be extremely appreciated. I feel like the second option (iterating through the group) is more likely to be possible, but I'm pretty new to python so I don't know.

Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 0):

Either use the loop to find the closest and also visible element:

```py
import math
```

```py
def sight(seen, viewer)
    for entity in viewer:
        currentDir = entity.Direction
        entityPos = pygame.math.Vector2(entity.rect.center)
    
        minE = None
        minCloseByDist = math.inf
        for e for e in seen.sprites():
            ePos = pygame.math.Vector2(e.rect.center)
            distance = entityPos.distance_to(ePos)
            if distance < entity.sight:
                closeByDist = distance / (e.size * e.size)
                if minE == None or closeByDist < minCloseByDist:
                    minE = e
                    minCloseByDist = minE

        if minE != None:
            # [...]
```

Or you can find all elements in view first and then the closest element:

```py
def sight(seen, viewer)
    for entity in viewer:
        currentDir = entity.Direction
        entityPos = pygame.math.Vector2(entity.rect.center)
    
        inSight = [e for e in seen.sprites() if entityPos.distance_to(pygame.math.Vector2(e.rect.center)) < entity.sight]
        if inSight:
            closeby = min([e for e in inSight], key=lambda e: (pos.distance_to(pygame.math.Vector2(e.rect.center)) / (e.size * e.size)))

            # [...]
```